# Display attributes of feature with clustering

Tags: openlayers-2

I have one KML layer that has roughly 900 features and I added OpenLayer.Cluster.Strategy to help the layer display a little quicker.

My KML displays the attributes when clicked on before clustering was enabled, but now the bubble displays 'undefined, undefined'.

How did the clustering change the extractAttributes property?

```
            var state = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("State Probation", {
            projection: map.displayProjection,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "state.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true,
                    extractAttributes: true
                })
            })
        });


        select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([sample, state],
            {
                clickout: true, toggle: false,
                multiple: true, hover: false,
                toggleKey: "ctrlKey", // ctrl key removes from selection
                multipleKey: "shiftKey" // shift key adds to selection
            });

        sample.events.on({
            "featureselected": onFeatureSelect,
            "featureunselected": onFeatureUnselect
        });

        state.events.on({
            "featureselected": onFeatureSelect,
            "featureunselected": onFeatureUnselect
        });

        map.addControl(select);
        select.activate();   

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());



    function onPopupClose(evt) {
        select.unselectAll();
    }

    function onFeatureSelect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        var selectedFeature = feature;
        var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
            "<h2>"+feature.attributes.name + "</h2>" + feature.attributes.description,
            null, true, onPopupClose
        );
        feature.popup = popup;
        map.addPopup(popup);
    }
    function onFeatureUnselect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        if(feature.popup) {
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            delete feature.popup;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGc2R.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGc2R.png) Marker may refer to: Marker pen, a felt-tipped pen used for drawing and/or coloring
Marker (linguistics), a morpheme that indicates some grammatical function
Marker (telecommunications), a special-purpose computer
Marker, a set of sewing patterns placed over cloth to be cut
Marker or Clapperboard, equipment used during filming
Paintball marker or paintball gun, an air gun
Biological marker, or biomarker, a substance used as an indicator of a biological state
Genetic marker, a DNA sequenc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When working with clusters, OpenLayers creates an array of attributes to store the attributes of all features in the cluster. When your points are in a cluster you need to access the array instead of the attribute directly. Example (untested):

```
function onFeatureSelect(event) {
    var feature = event.feature;
    var selectedFeature = feature;
    var text = ""
    if(feature.cluster) {
        for(var i=0; i<feature.cluster.length; i++) {
            text += "<h2>"+feature.cluster[i].attributes.name + "</h2>" + 
                   feature.cluster[i].attributes.description + "\n";
        }
    } else {
        text = "<h2>"+feature.attributes.name + "</h2>" + feature.attributes.description;
    }

    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
        feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
        new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
        text,
        null, true, onPopupClose
    );
    feature.popup = popup;
    map.addPopup(popup);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
function onFeatureSelect(event) {
    var feature = event.feature;
    var layerName = event.feature.layer.name;
    var content = "unInitialized";
    // alert ('selected this feature='+feature.id+ '<br/>Atributos: '+feature.attributes.description);
    if ( (feature.attributes.name > '') || (feature.attributes.description > '') ) {
        content = feature.attributes.name + '<br/>'+feature.attributes.description;
    } else {
        if (feature.cluster) {
            content = feature.attributes.count + ' ' + layerName ;
            for (var i = 0; i < feature.attributes.count; i++) {
                    var feat = feature.cluster[i];
                    content += '<br/>'+feat.attributes.name;
            }
        } else {
            content = 'NOT a cluster either';
        }
    }

    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
                             feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                             new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
                             content,
                             null, true, onFeatureUnselect);
    popup.setBackgroundColor('white');
    feature.popup = popup;
    map.addPopup(popup);
    // GLOBAL variable, in case popup is destroyed by clicking CLOSE box
    lastfeature = feature;
    // alert ('select'+lastfeature.name);
}
```